# initialization of 'const char **' from incompatible pointer type 'char *'

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I am new in learning C. I have an issue in returning double star pointer from the function.

This is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#include "api.h"

void init() {
  // You can initiate and calculate things here
}

/**
 * Return the given list in reversed order. Each element in the given list contains a single character.
 * 
 * typedef struct {
 *   int count;
 *   const char * * elements;
 * } string_list;
 * 
 * list_of_chars: string_list
 * 
 * returns: string_list
 */
string_list reverse(string_list list_of_chars) {
  // Write your code here
  char X[list_of_chars.count];
  
  //X[0] = *list_of_chars.elements[0];
  
  for (int i = 0; i < list_of_chars.count;i++){
  X[i] = *list_of_chars.elements[i];
  }
  printf("%c", X[0]);

  string_list return_value = {
    .count = 0,
    .elements = &X[0],
  };
  return return_value;
}
```

But I am getting initialization of 'const char **' from incompatible pointer type 'char *'. I tried multiple solutions but non of them worked.

Comment: @Dai it's in the code comments above the function

Comment: `X` is function scoped (on the stack). It goes out of scope when the function returns. You want: `char *X = malloc(list_of_chars.count);`

Comment: I did not got what is the use of the comments above the code (e.g., init function and the struct)
But I tried to malloc the X pointer with return X instead of &X, but still not worked. maybe I missed something.

Comment: I missed the original intent. You want: `char **X = malloc(list_of_chars.count * sizeof(*X));` and `X[list_of_chars.count - 1 - i] = strdup(*list_of_chars.elements[i]);`

Comment: implicit declaration of function 'strdup'; did you mean 'strcmp'? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   30 |     X[list_of_chars.count - 1 - i] = strdup(*list_of_chars.elements[i]);
      |                                      ^~~~~~
      |                                      strcmp
solution.c:30:36: error: assignment to 'char *' from 'int' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Werror=int-conversion]
   30 |     X[list_of_chars.count - 1 - i] = strdup(*list_of_chars.elements[i]);
      |                                    ^

Comment: Also, `.count = list_of_chars.count`

Comment: Tried it but got 
implicit declaration of function 'strdup'; did you mean 'strcmp'? 
And
error: assignment to 'char *' from 'int' makes pointer from integer without a cast

Comment: Oops, I'm on mobile. Remove `*` from the `strdup` call

Comment: Add: `#include <string.h>`

Comment: done it but still error :(
*** X[list_of_chars.count - 1 - i] = strdup(list_of_chars.elements[i]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Side note:* As I mentioned in the top comments, I was limited to what I could do on mobile. I'm back at my desk.

Issues were:

1. `X` is function scoped, so it goes out of scope when the function returns. We need to use `malloc` [so we need `stdlib.h`]
2. Because `elements` is a `const char **`, then we need `const char **X`

We need to use [should use] `strdup` to duplicate the elements.

Otherwise, both lists will *share* the same data. This *may* the desired intent. But, it's not clear from the problem description what the correct code should be.

Most lists should be fully independent from one another. The original code does *not* do this. So, the lists are sharing the data. But, if that's true, why bother to create a separate list? We could just "reverse" it by indexing in the reverse direction *without* creating a new list:

```
for (int i = list.count - 1;  i >= 0;  --i)
```

---

So, I've chosen to duplicate the strings. Original behavior (shared strings) when compiled with `-DNODUP`.

Here's the refactored code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#if 0
#include "api.h"
#else
typedef struct {
    int count;
    const char **elements;
} string_list;
#endif

void
init()
{
    // You can initiate and calculate things here
}

/**
 * Return the given list in reversed order. Each element in the given list contains a single character.
 *
 * typedef struct {
 *   int count;
 *   const char * * elements;
 * } string_list;
 *
 * list_of_chars: string_list
 *
 * returns: string_list
 */
string_list
reverse(string_list list)
{
    const char **X = malloc(sizeof(*X) * list.count);

    // share the strings
#if NODUP
    for (int i = 0; i < list.count; i++)
        X[list.count - 1 - i] = list.elements[i];

    // make lists independent (more usual/expected)
#else
    for (int i = 0; i < list.count; i++)
        X[list.count - 1 - i] = strdup(list.elements[i]);
#endif

    string_list ret = {
        .count = list.count,
        .elements = X,
    };

    return ret;
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> In the link above was the exercise page where we can choose GCC for C. I pasted your code exactly to the website bit still see same errors.

Okay, finally ... ;-)

1. The website uses an *ancient* version of the C standard (e.g. C99). This does *not* have `strdup`.
2. The website will [forcibly] do a `#include "api.h"` before including the code, so there is a conflict with the definition I used.

Here is the corrected code (which runs successfully on the website):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#if 1
#include "api.h"
#else
typedef struct {
    int count;
    const char **elements;
} string_list;
#endif

void
init()
{
    // You can initiate and calculate things here
}

/**
 * Return the given list in reversed order. Each element in the given list contains a single character.
 *
 * typedef struct {
 *   int count;
 *   const char * * elements;
 * } string_list;
 *
 * list_of_chars: string_list
 *
 * returns: string_list
 */
string_list
reverse(string_list list)
{
    const char **X = malloc(sizeof(*X) * list.count);

    // share the strings
#if 1
    for (int i = 0; i < list.count; i++)
        X[list.count - 1 - i] = list.elements[i];

    // make lists independent (more usual/expected)
#else
    for (int i = 0; i < list.count; i++)
        X[list.count - 1 - i] = strdup(list.elements[i]);
#endif

    string_list ret = {
        .count = list.count,
        .elements = X,
    };

    return ret;
}
```

*Side note:* I'd get a good book on C and study that to get more basic knowledge of C. Trying to use "competition" websites isn't the best way, IMO.

A number of the issues you've seen (but did not understand) would have been obvious with a better basic understanding of C syntax and semantics.

Here's a list: [The Definitive C Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Thank you alot for answer. I tried it but I got these
* solution.c:10:3: error: conflicting types for 'string_list'
*  note: previous declaration of 'reverse' was here
* : implicit declaration of function 'strdup'; did you mean 'strcmp'? [-Werror=implicit-

https://app.futureskill.com/exercise/5f609c49aa3c5b44f6359a26

Comment: @AliAmma Try using my posted code _exactly_ (i.e. copy and paste it). It compiles cleanly even with `-Wall -O2`. You must be mixing and matching. I commented out: `#include "api.h"` [because you didn't post it] and copied the `struct` definition from the function comments. If you do "both", they will conflict. I'm not sure why you're linking to _python_ code.

Comment: @AliAmma Also, I added necessary [but missing] `#include` statements. So, just copying the updated function may not be enough.

Comment: In the link above was the exercise page where we can choose GCC for C. I pasted your code exactly to the website bit still see same errors.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your suggestion. will do as  you said :)